# Make Different users in Unix or Linux and Set their individual permissions

Tags: linux, unix

I want to make different users at my server(say 22.23.34.*) and set each user's permissions to their particular directory only.
Lets say my server is having three directories
Directory A, B, C

=> Now root user should be able to access all the directories. He can update , delete etc in all directories.

=> now let's say I make another user "A". Now I want that "A" can do anything only in his own directory but can only other user's directories. He should be able to perform CRUD operations in Directory "A" only to which he is allocated to.

What will be the commands used to create such schema ? Any idea ?

Comment: Which distro are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the user by the syntax:

> `useradd` *[options] username*

e.g., `useradd aruz`

To allow users to see each others' home directories, do

```
chmod 755 /home/userA
```

... or whatever home directory paths look like on your system.

To *prevent* users from being able to see each others' home directories, do

```
chmod 700 /home/userA
```

And for good measure, you could do

```
chown userA /home/userA
```

but that will almost certainly be set that way by default.

If your system has ACLs, you can use them to implement finer-grained access control.